# .htaccess file redirecting to the index page instead of a custom 404 page

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a website where I need to show a custom error page. I have done it before by editing the .htaccess file.

This is what I have in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?domain.*$ [NC] 
 RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|jpeg)$ http://www.domain.com [L]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
  ErrorDocument 404 /error404.php
   ErrorDocument 403 /error404.php
   Options -Indexes 

      RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+page\.php\?url=([^\s&]+) [NC]
     RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
       RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /page.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The page always redirects to the index page instead of showing the error page. What am I doing wrong? I have tried removing many lines, but nothing helped.

Comment: Your last rule is forwarding all non-file, non-directories to `/page.php` therefore `ErrorDocument 404 /error404.php` is being ignored.

Comment: It looks like you're routing all requests to page.php. As far as the webserver is concerned, every request is valid. If you want to display a 404 page you're going to have to do it at the application level.

Comment: is this possible to write the htaccess like if any extension like .php or .html is there in the file name and it doesn't exist then only direct to 404 page

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /error404.php
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?domain.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|jpeg)$ http://www.domain.com [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+page\.php\?url=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ /page.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This will load your custom 404 handler if request is for some extension like `.php` or `.html`.